# Remove all elements from a List after a particular index

Tags: java

Is there any convenient way in List/ArrayList by which we can remove all elements of a List after a particular index. Instead of manually looping through it for removing.

To be more explanatory, if I have a list of 10 elements, I want to mention index 3 and then all elements after index 3 gets removed and my list would consist of only starting 4 elements now (counts from 0)

Answer (score 185, accepted):

```
list.subList(4, list.size()).clear();
```

[Sublist operations are reflected in the original list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList%28int,%20int%29), so this clears everything from index 4 inclusive to `list.size()` exclusive, a.k.a. everything after index 3. Range removal is specifically used as an example in the documentation:

> This method eliminates the need for explicit range operations (of the
>   sort that commonly exist for arrays). Any operation that expects a
>   list can be used as a range operation by passing a subList view
>   instead of a whole list. For example, the following idiom removes a
>   range of elements from a list:
>
> ```
>      list.subList(from, to).clear();
> ```

Comment: If `list` is created from `Arrays.asList()`, you will get a error of `UnsupportedOperationException`, just make the input as an `ArrayList` by `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three"));` will work, please refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32929410/java-8-unsupportedoperationexception-on-sublist-clear

Comment: @Galley: Well, of course if you try to remove stuff from a list that doesn't support removing stuff, it's not going to work.

Answer (score 17):

Using sublist() and clear(),

```
public class Count
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        arrayList.add("1");
        arrayList.add("2");
        arrayList.add("3");
        arrayList.add("4");
        arrayList.add("5");
        arrayList.subList(2, arrayList.size()).clear();
        System.out.println(arrayList.size());
    }
}
```