# java 8 UnsupportedOperationException on subList.clear()

Tags: java, list

Here is the code that throws the exception on strList5's subList.clear() invocation:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public static List<String> removeRange(List<String> strList, int         maxElementsToBeAllowedInList) {
    if (strList.size() > maxElementsToBeAllowedInList) {
        System.out.println("Clearing out sublist: ["
                + strList.subList(maxElementsToBeAllowedInList, strList.size()) + "]");
        strList.subList(maxElementsToBeAllowedInList, strList.size()).clear();
    }
    return strList;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> strList1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> strList2 = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three");
    List<String> strList3 = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three", "four", "five");
    List<String> strList4 = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six");
    List<String> strList5 = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight");

    try {
        System.out.println("Before modification strList1: [" + strList1 + "]");
        ListTruncateEndTest.removeRange(strList1, 5);
        System.out.println("After modification strList1: [" + strList1 + "]");

        System.out.println("Before modification strList2: [" + strList2 + "]");
        ListTruncateEndTest.removeRange(strList2, 5);
        System.out.println("After modification strList1: [" + strList2 + "]");

        System.out.println("Before modification strList3: [" + strList3 + "]");
        ListTruncateEndTest.removeRange(strList3, 5);
        System.out.println("After modification strList1: [" + strList3 + "]");

        System.out.println("Before modification strList4: [" + strList4 + "]");
        ListTruncateEndTest.removeRange(strList4, 5);
        System.out.println("After modification strList4: [" + strList4 + "]");

        System.out.println("Before modification strList5: [" + strList5 + "]");
        ListTruncateEndTest.removeRange(strList5, 5);
        System.out.println("After modification strList5: [" + strList5 + "]");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: [" + e.toString() + "]");
    }
}

Before modification strList1: [[]]
After modification strList1: [[]]
Before modification strList2: [[one, two, three]]
After modification strList2: [[one, two, three]]
Before modification strList3: [[one, two, three, four, five]]
After modification strList3: [[one, two, three, four, five]]
Before modification strList4: [[one, two, three, four, five, six]]
Clearing out sublist: [[six]]
Error: [java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException]
```

Is there something wrong with how I am clearing the sublist? or is this a Bug in Java 8?
My version of Java 8 on Mac is:
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: You might also consider to print out the stacktrace of your exception `ex.printStackTrace()` instead of only the message.

Answer (score 8):

The lists returned by `Arrays.asList` are fixed length, so calling `clear` on `subList`s throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

You need to use `ArrayList` instead.

```
List<String> strList2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three"));
```

Comment: Thanks Paul,  When I used new ArrayList<> and added elements to it I did not get the error which matches your answer.  U posted the answer before I found out, so U get the credit for it.